# Adding data to debug.log file of CakePHP 2

Tags: php, cakephp, logging, cakephp-2.0

In my CakePHP 2.2 application I get a "notice" inside my debug.log file. I get this warning nearly every day but I couldn't solve the problem. So I need to write some additional data inside debug.log. But I want to write that data when this "notice" occurs.

For example I get this notice:

```
2012-09-26 19:53:01 Notice: Notice (8):
 Trying to get property of non-object in
  [/var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/View/Tools/index.ctp, line 42]
Trace:
include - APP/View/Tools/index.ctp, line 42
View::_evaluate() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 920
View::_render() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 883
View::render() - CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 475
Controller::render() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 957
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 193
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 161
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 96
```

I want to add all session variables into debug.log file when this notice occurs.
How can I do this?
Can I change `lib/Cake/Log/Cakelog.php`
What should I write and where?

Edit: I paste the related code snippet:

```
39       <?php if ($auth) { ?>
40        <form class="well" >
41
42            <?php if (isset($user->profile_url)) {
43            echo '<img src="'.$user->profile_url.'" width="48" height="48"/>';
44        } ?>
45
46            <strong><?php echo $user->screen_name; if (isset($user->name)) { echo " (" . $user->name . ")"; } ?></strong><br/>
47            <small><?php if (isset($user->description)) { echo $user->description; } ?> </small><br/>
48            <small><?php if (isset($user->url)) { echo $user->url; } ?> </small><br/>
49            <br/>
```

Comment: What is it you're trying to do on line 42 of `/app/View/Tools/index.ctp`?

Comment: I'm trying to reach an object's member in that code snippet. Although I put my code inside an "if-isset-then" in line 42, I still get this notice. So maybe I can guess the cause from session variables..

Comment: It would help to see the code ;)

Comment: Hmmmm can you tell me what `$user` is? Is it a variable that's the result of a find call?

Comment: Yes $user is an std object, which is get after a Twitter API call.